# Using a file .shp with ESRI Geo Tools for Hadoop

Tags: shapefile, json, hadoop, hive

I've a file .shp that I would like to load into a TABLE using HIVE with ESRI Geo Tool for Hadoop.

These tools read JSON files and I've tried to convert my file into a .json format using GDAL Library with command `ogr2ogr -f geoJSON com.json com.shp`

This format isn't suitable for ESRI GeoTools for Hadoop that need of unenclosed JSON. How can I correctly convert my shapefile?

Comment: I think this does what you are looking for: https://github.com/Esri/geojson-utils

Comment: Building on this, an explanation of unenclosed JSON and enclosed JSON in relation to Esri tech https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/JSON-Formats

Comment: see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126252/how-to-load-geographic-data-into-hadoop-hive-and-then-to-be-able-to-call-spati